# How to update my toolkit? Extended Data Grid Cell Template Text Box Value Without Rebinding Data Grid in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem in my task. I use to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) technology to implement one Functionality as for I want to update Data Grid Cell Template Value Without Refresh the Data Grid.

Inside Cell Template I have taken one Text Box Control for update Value in  Column Field. My requirement is whenever I give to text box value only is update Particular Row not Refresh All data Grid.

As per my understanding below use code and snap shot image.

[Data Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E26I4.png)

```
        Border bd = (Border)bdName;
        MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid dg = (MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid)bd.FindName("DataGrid");
        MyToolkit.Controls.DataGridTemplatedColumn dtc = (MyToolkit.Controls.DataGridTemplatedColumn)dg.Columns[2];
        DataTemplate dte = (DataTemplate)dtc.CellTemplate;
        dte.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, "0000");
        TextBox tx = (TextBox)dte.LoadContent();
        tx.Text = ((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)sender).Text.ToString();
        TextBox tx = (TextBox)dte.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, "7777");
```

Comment: What's the toolkit? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I used to Third party Controls MyToolKit.Extended Data Grid .https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid  ,This Control i m using our Project

Comment: I want to only Update particular Cell template Value  Without refresh the Data Grid .